# .clear() does not clear the existing Text inside the Text box is there any other way to clear the Text?

Tags: python

I tried by adding this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/input").send_Keys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a", Keys.DELETE))
```

But still, I was not able to clear the existing text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not do it like that, what you want to do is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/input").clear()
```

And that's all you need. If that doesn't work you can try

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

.....

input_field1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/input")

for i in input_field1.get_attribute('value'):
    input_field1.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
input_field1.send_keys("new input")
```